# What vim setting controls this behavior?

Tags: vim

`hello world`

If I place my cursor right after `o` on `hello` and go into insert mode, then type `<CR>`, `world` does not have a space in front of it on the second line. But with a vanilla vimrc file, the space character in front of `world` originally is preserved on the newline. I can't figure out what setting is controlling this particular behavior.

Comment: You can use `:set all` to see a list of all settings and what values they currently have.  You might want to look it over and see if you spot anything with a plausible name.

Comment: Can you post your vimrc?

Comment: If you ask us to tell you what's wrong with your settings, the least you could do is to actually show us your settings. Especially if you have noticed a different behavior with and without your vimrc and apparently didn't think about taking 3 minutes to perform bisection on it.

Comment: My vimrc is quite massive, thus I was reluctant to post it, and also the reason why I was looking for a quick answer from someone knowledgable in the first place. Here it is in case anyone is still interested in helping to figure out what caused this: https://github.com/terryma/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Answer (score 2):

By any chance is `autoindent` set on?  That will make the white space at the beginning of a line match the previous line, and since the previous line has no leading whitespace, vim would delete the whitespace.  (I just tested this.)

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work for my current vimrc. I did test this on a vanilla vimrc by turning it on, and it indeed squashed the whitespace. But in my vimrc, it didn't unsquash it by turning it off. There must be another setting somewhere...